# Opencv 3: cudarithm.hpp not installed on linux when building without cuda

Tags: opencv3.0

I have a question regarding the CUDA modules in OpenCV 3. Formerly in OpenCV 2 there was the `opencv_gpu` module and there was always a `opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp` file in the include folder. It would be moved there during install whether OpenCV was built with CUDA or without. In the latter case however, CUDA functions would not be usable later in the code, which could be checked by invoking `cv::gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()` which would then always return 0. This way a program that used CUDA could be compiled with versions of OpenCV that were built with CUDA, as well as with ones built without CUDA.

In Opencv 3.0 the CUDA functions have been moved to the modules `cudaarithm`, `cudaimgproc`, `cudafilters`, `cudawarping` and so on. They are only available if you add the opencv contrib repository.

Now, I was creating a program that uses cuda. Then I realized, that when building and installing OpenCV without CUDA, meaining the machine does not support CUDA and the NVIDIA cuda toolkit is not installed, the header files for the CUDA modules are not copied into the `include` folder when installing. This way the program doesn't compile. How do you compile a program using the OpenCV CUDA modules with a build that was built without CUDA in OpenCV 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, at least for OpenCV 3.1 it appears not to be a problem. The cuda modules have also been moved back to the main repository.

It is necessary to have a version of OpenCV compiled with CUDA. That can be done also on a machine without an Nvidia GPU. The Nvidia CUDA toolkit has to be installed (just ignore the warning message about the GPU). The graphics driver, however, is not required. This way compiling OpenCV with CUDA should not be a problem also on a machine that is not CUDA-enabled.

In your project you can then just include the `cudaarithm` etc. modules and perform the check if any CUDA devices are available at runtime, just like before.

Answer (score 1):

Previous Version OpenCV upto 2.3 default build was with CUDA from that onwards if you want to run Opencv with cuda support you have build OpenCV from source with CUDA [Check This Guide](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/).
You must have a CUDA enabled GPU to run Opencv with CUDA. [NVIDIA CUDA enabled GPU List](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)

Comment: I know. That was not my question. I just want to know if it is still possible to build a project that uses OpenCV (and its gpu modules) with an Opencv-build that was built without the CUDA-support. Formerly the `opencv_gpu` libs and headers were always there, regardless of whether OpenCV was built with or without CUDA. Now they are only there, if it's built _with_ CUDA.

Comment: As I said there is no way to run Programs that uses cuda from opencv3.0 without CUDA support. Recently I tried that a lot though my GPU was cuda enabled but couldn't build opencv from Source with CUDA as its compute capability was 1.1. Still you can but I don't think there is anyother way :/